# @override error in RAD IDE - Compiler 1.6

Tags: java, overriding

The error I am right know facing is stated below:

> method `commandCompleted(CommandEvent)` of type `new CommandListener(){}` must override
>   a superclass method.

Even though I have included `@override` in the method, it still shows an error.

My environment is RAD IDE version 7.0.0. I installed JDK 1.6. What else do I have to do?

Comment: It would also be helpful to include what classes you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure RAD is based of Eclipse so you should be able to check your Compliance level by going to Window->Preferences
Then navigating down Java->Compiler. Check the value of the "Compiler Compliance level" it should be 1.6.

If it is 1.6 then as Dave said you have not actually overidden anything and should remove the notation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1. Your method signature is wrong, hence you're using `@Override` on a method that doesn't actually override anything.
2. You're project's JDK compliance is set to 1.5, where you can't use `@Override` on an interface method's implementation.